# VNC rendering is all fragmented

Tags: vnc, graphics, optimization

I have my VNC server so configured, that it requires me to establish an ssh tunnel and connect to it on `localhost:1` with my vncviewer. Now the connectivity seems to work fine but the rendering of the desktop comes out all fragmented and is hardly usable if at all. Is there some additional compression I can activate or other ways on how I can tweak this?

[image]